# Probability of an event happening if at least one of 2 events happen

Tags: probability

So I'm doing a probability question, the probability of event A happening is $0.4$, event B is $0.7$. What is the probability of only event A happening given that at least one of the two events happen?

What I have tried so far is getting the probability of at least one of two events happening, which I got $0.82$ from adding the two and subtracting their sum. From here I'm not too sure where to go, I have thought about the simple operations I could do such as multiplying the $0.82$ by the probability of the $2$, but none of them seem to be the right choice.

EDIT: sorry I forgot to mention that it's given that these two events are independent

Comment: If you do not know anything about the independence of $A$ and $B$ then there is not enough information to conclude anything.  $P(A\cap B)$ could be anything between $0.1$ and $0.4$, so you can't even conclude what $P(A\cup B)$ is.

Comment: my bad, I forgot to add the fact that they are independent

Comment: So then, you are tasked with calculating $P(A\mid A\cup B)$ which by definition of conditional probability is $P(A\mid A\cup B)=\frac{P(A\cap (A\cup B))}{P(A\cup B)}$, notice now that $A\cap (A\cup B) = A$ and notice that $P(A\cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$ which by the independence assumption you know is $P(A)+P(B)-P(A)\cdot P(B)$

Comment: So since top is $A$ it's $0.4$ and bottom is $0.82$, then the answer is $0.487$? The answer on the back of my textbook says the answer to this question is supposed to be $0.146$, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Ah, **only event A**, so instead we are actually looking for $P(A\setminus B\mid A\cup B)$

Comment: is that $A$ divided by $B$ in the first part of the bracket?

Comment: Thats $A$ without $B$ or alternatively $A$ setminus $B$, i.e. $A\cap B^c$, which in this case is $P(A)-P(A\cap B)$

Answer (score 1):

You want to find $P(A \cap \neg B|A \cup B)$.

$$P(A \cap \neg B|A \cup B) = \frac{P((A \cap \neg B) \cap (A \cup B))}{P(A \cup B)} = \frac{P(A \cap \neg B)}{P(A \cup B)} = \frac{P(A) P(\neg B)}{P(A \cup B)} = \frac{P(A) P(\neg B)}{1-P(\neg A)P(\neg B)} = \frac{0.4 \times 0.3}{1-0.6 \times 0.3} = \frac{0.12}{0.82} \approx 0.146$$

I think is helps to look at these problems visually too. Since the two events are independent we can draw the event space to look like the following picture (imagine you can take a horizontal line to sample the event space):

[image: Probability of A and not B given either is happening]